# How to convert from string to UnityEngine.UI.Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to unity and I am making a game.

I want to print on a text label, but I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'

How should I do this?

I've tried ToString, but I think that is for going to a string.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class typewrite : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int i;
    public string text;
    public AudioClip clicksound;
    public AudioSource click;
    public string label = "";


    void Start()
    {
        click.clip = clicksound;
    }

    void message() {

        for(i=0; i<=text.Length; i++) {

            label.text += text.Substring(0, i);
            click.Play;

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks,

EthanZoneCoding

It should print one letter at a time:

E

Ex

Exa

Exam

Examp

Exampl

Example

And make a sound every time

Comment: the forloop will not be done over a course of frames, so even if it adds it 1 by 1, for the most part your text will just appear.. You might do better with a coroutine for wait 0.1f seconds between character displays

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs in the following line

```
public Text label = "";
```

You cannot assign an empty string to a property of type Text. You should remove the assignment of the empty string from this line.

If you want to set an empty string as text at the beginning of the script, you can do this in the start method:

```
void Start()
{
    click.clip = clicksound;
    label.text = "";
}
```

Comment: Now it is telling me things like "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected"

Comment: and } expected.

Comment: You have one more error in your script in the following line `click.Play;`. You want to call the Play method so you must add braces: `click.Play();`

Comment: Did that. Still is telling me to put closing curly brackets in right after the opening ones

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code

1. As the compiler error already said and mentioned in the other answer you can not "convert" a `string` to a `Text` component.

   You rather have to assign it to the `text` property of the `Text` component like

   ```
   label.text = "example";
   ```

You should do this e.g. in `Start`

2. You are missing brackets for the call of

   ```
   click.Play();
   ```

   though actually I would rather use [`PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html)

   ```
    click.PlayOneShot(clickSound, 1.0f);
   ```
3. In order to see your text appear bit by bit you have to use your code e.g. to a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

   ```
   public void message() 
   {
       // Stop other routines to not have multiple concurrent instances
       StopAllCoroutines();
       StartCoroutine(MessageRoutine());
   }

   private IEnumerator MessageRoutine()
   {
       for(i=0; i<=text.Length; i++)
       {
           label.text += text.Substring(0, i);
           click.Play();
           //or
           click.PlayOneShot();

           // Wait for seconds e.g. 0.1
           // yields makes the routine "interrupt" here,
           // render the frame and continue in the next frame from here
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
       }
   }
   ```